# falha ao usar get_header no wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Estou montando um sistema com wordpress para facilitar o desenvolvimento e eu criei um tema e coloquei na pasta \wp-content\themes.
Os arquivos index.php, header.php e footer.php estão na pasta \wp-content\themes\Themacuria.
Eu coloquei na raiz do WP uma pasta com os arquivos php.
Ao usar o comando get_header(); deu erro fatal.
Acredito que o meu problema está com a estrutura do WP.
Como eu devo proceder?[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`get_header()` é um método do WP. Portanto, para ser usado, ele precisa, de alguma maneira, estar dentro do contexto do WP. Pelo que pude entender da sua pergunta, você criou o tema (i.e., `index.php`, `header.php`, e arquivos do genero), mas está tentando usar o método em um arquivo que não está dentro do tema. O erro fatal é, portanto, natural.

O WordPress trabalha com uma [Hierarquia de modelos](https://codex.wordpress.org/pt-br:Hierarquia_de_Modelos_WordPress), a qual permite que você crie páginas de vários tipos na sua aplicação seguindo uma certa lógica. Tentar burlar tal lógica (por exemplo, tentar criar páginas em arquivos fora da estrutura do CMS) geralmente não é uma boa idéia.

Dito isso, acredito que você tenha duas opções:

1. Usar a lógica do WP para criar as páginas

   Existem vários tutoriais na internet de como montar um tema para o WP de maneira correta, como [este aqui](https://www.wptotal.com/como-criar-um-template-wordpress-parte-1/). Experimente criar um *template* para uma página, e dentro dele invocar o método `get_header()` (aliás, experimente invocá-lo no próprio `index.php`, ative o seu tema no painél do WP, acesse o site e veja o que acontece). [Aqui](https://codex.wordpress.org/pt-br:Modelos_de_P%C3%A1ginas) você encontra boas instruções de como fazer isso.
2. Incorporar as funções do WP nos seus arquivos.

   Particularmente, eu não gosto dessa solução, apesar de já tê-la visto sendo usada extensivamente por aí, principalmente quando se trata de integração com aplicações legadas. Mas, em casos raros (que não acredito que seja o seu), ela é a única opção. Trata-se de incluir, forçadamente, os métodos do WP em arquivos `.php` que estão fora da lógica do mesmo. Para isso, basta que você faça um `require`, da seguinte maneira,

   ```
   require('/caminho/para/o/arquivo/wp-blog-header.php');
   ```

   no arquivo externo (que, no seu caso, acredito ser o que você esteja tentando acessar). Isso faz com que o arquivo tenha acesso à métodos do WP. Você pode ler sobre este tipo de integração [aqui](http://codex.wordpress.org/Integrating_WordPress_with_Your_Website) (em inglês).

Como eu disse, a segunda solução não me agrada, e acredito que, pelo que entendi do seu problema, seja mais vantajoso usar a própria arquitetura do WP.