# Atributo de Página, modelo, em um "projeto" do wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Tenho um site em Wordpress, da qual algumas páginas eu uso ao invés do editor wordpress, arquivo `.php` com um `Template Name`, de tal modo aponto no wordpress o modelo, localizado nos atributos de página.

Porém neste site, eu uso também a parte de "projetos" para criar o portfólio, em geral todos seguem um padrão básico montado direto no wordpress com o montador `divi`, porém alguns projetos em específico é um pouco mais trabalhado a página, um deles faço várias coisas em php mesmo, animações css, js, svg, entre outras coisas. Montei uma prévia da página já em um arquivo .php com um template name, mas percebi que para os projetos não tem esta aba `Atributos da Página`.

Há alguma maneira de fazer um projeto específico pegar um arquivo .php ao invés de ser apenas montado direto no editor do wordpress?

Obrigado.

Comment: Você quer executar um arquivo '.php' qualquer fora da lógica do WP, é isso?

Comment: @CaioFelipePereira eu tenho um arquivo php, que eu importo o header `    get_header();` e o footer, com um template name. Pois executo várias condicionais direto no php, de nível de usuário da qual consulto uma base externa do wordpress. Com páginas beleza, faço isso já, mas com os "projetos" não achei esta opção, e nem sei se há alguma maneira.

Comment: @CaioFelipePereira sei que não está mt bem nos "padrões wordpress" haha mas este projeto está nesta primeira versão com muita coisa "remendada" na pura gambiarra por questões de tempo, etc.. e assim que lançar esta versão já vai começar a ser desenvolvida de maneira descente uma v2. então se houver uma maneira mesmo que `goHorse` estou aceitando. haha

Comment: Mas o que são "projetos"? O que é um montador "divi"? A sua pergunta está bem confusa... [nessa resposta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/133787/falha-ao-usar-get-header-no-wordpress/133858#133858) eu falo sobre algo que TALVEZ possa te ajudar, mas não sei...

Comment: Os "projetos" é de um plugin de portfólio do wordpress. [imagem de projetos](http://unkdigital.com.br/images/projetos-wordpress.PNG). o construtor divi também é um plugin que veio junto com o tema q eu uso, serve para facilitar criação de páginas, [imagem do construtor](http://unkdigital.com.br/images/construtor-divi.PNG). Agora quando eu edito uma página normal, existe o menu "atributo da página" da qual posso selecionar o modelo [como nesta imagem](http://unkdigital.com.br/images/edicao-de-pagina-attr.PNG)

Comment: mas quando edito um projeto, não existe essa aba de atributos, da qual posso selecionar o modelo. [como nesta imagem](http://unkdigital.com.br/images/edicao-de-projeto.PNG)

Comment: no canto superior direito existe um ícone chamado "opções de tela". clique nele

Comment: @CaioFelipePereira não há a opção dos atributos, ele funciona como um post os projetos, há alguma maneira de fazer um post pegar php? ou a unica saída vai ser aquele plugin de colocar php direto pelo editor do wordpress msm? @.@

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A caixa "Atributos de Página" só existe para Post Types hierárquicos, e o seu Projetos não deve ser.

Nesse caso você pode renomear o arquivo PHP e alterar a Hierarquia de Templates a seu favor.

Exemplo: se a URL do projeto é example.com/projeto/nome-do-projeto, você pode fazer:

```
add_filter( 'template_include', 'redireciona_projeto' );
function redireciona_projeto( $template ) {
    global $post;
    if ( 'nome-do-projeto' == $post->post_name ) {
        $novotemplate = locate_template( array( 'nome-do-arquivo.php' ) );
        if ( '' != $novotemplate ) {
            return $novotemplate ;
        }
    }
    return $template;
}
```

Comment: Cara, Muiito obrigado, isto resolveu meu problema! eu não sabia desse filter `template_include`. perfeito! unica alteração que precisei fazer foi trocar `$post->slug` para `$post->post_name` para pegar o slug corretamente. Muito obrigado novamente! :D

Comment: Opa, valeu. Vacilei com o nome da propriedade, já editei pra corrigir.